# How to Increase the width of Group tree view in Crystal Report of ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-2008

how can i adjust the width of 
grouptreeview of a crystal report 
in asp.net to provide full view to user

```
How to Increase the width of Group tree view in Crystal Report of ASP.NET
```

Comment: Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work. Learn more…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using the `property` of 
`CrystalReportViewer` 
The `ratio` between `pagewidth` and `treeview` width